# How to Combine Multiple View Updates Into One ListView?

Tags: dominotogo

I have multiple views in multiple nsf databases that I want to perform a view.update on, build an array of records, and show the results in one ListView. What would be the best way to do this in regards to performance? One idea that came to mind was to:

1. Perform .update() method on views
2. In callback of each update, push records to a (global?) array
3. Set array to ListView

Am I thinking about this correctly? Is there an example of doing this in Domino To Go?

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would chain the .update() methods on the views and in the callback of the final update I would sue a DTGDatabase object with getAllEntriesByKey() method to get the records, it's faster than using NotesView.getAllEntriesByKey of each view.

Or use DTGDatabase.getAllEntriesBySQL with a proper SQL statement, that way you can do a JOIN and it's the fastest option.

Comment: With the NotesView object I am loop through each entry and use the getColumnValue method to set values. How can I do this with the DTGDatabase object? I realize you can use `for (e in entries)` to loop, but is there a similar "getColumnValue" method for getting individual values?

Comment: DTGDatabase.getAllEntriesBySQL() returns an array where each element contains another array with column values. Use `for (e in entries) {DTG.log("first column value": + e[0]) }` for example.

Comment: Thanks! The syntax for getting column values is working. The remaining  issue I'm having is that the tables I need to combine are in different databases. You mentioned using a JOIN, and I've tried this: https://gist.github.com/rbuening28/20da76ff6a30fb4135a4 but I'm getting an error "no such table". Any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry to say but you cannot combine data from different SQLite databases using SQL... I thought you're working with one database. I think your best bet is to get data from one database in one array, then from the other database into another array, and combine both afterwards. Unfortunately, this will not be the fastest way...

Comment: I ended up combining an array. Thanks.